# Ubuntu Snappy XAMPP Pi2

Tags: xampp, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, snap

Is there a way to install xampp in Ubuntu snappy 14.04 Raspberry Pi 2?

Comment: No Raspberry Pi images exist for 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but you can be the first to create such a snap (there is not Ubuntu Core 14.04 btw). You can join the snappy playpen and help us creating one there: https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen